# How to find similar text in a large string?

Tags: php, string, similarity, sentence-similarity

I have a large string str and a needle ndl. Now, I need to find similar text of ndl from the string str. For example,

> SOURCE: "This is a demo text and I love you about this".
>
> NEEDLE: "I you love"
>
> OUTPUT: "I love you"
>
> ---
>
> SOURCE: "I have a unique idea. Do you need one?".
>
> NEEDLE: "a unik idia"
>
> OUTPUT: "a unique idea"

I found that I can do this using similarity measures like cosine or manhatton similarity measure. However, I think implementation of this algorithms will be difficult. Would you please suggest me any easy or fastest way to do this maybe using any library function of php? TIA

Answer (score 1):

There is no PHP native function to achieve this goal.However the possibilities of PHP is just limited by your imagination.We can't on SO suggest libraries to achieve your goal and you need to keep in mind that this kind of questions can be flagged as off-topic. So instead of suggesting some libraries I will just point you into the directions you need to explore.

As designed ,your question suggest that you don't need  simple strings match functions like `stripos` and co and a regex can't achieve this. For examples

> unik and unique

and also

> idia and idea

can't be matched by those functions. So You need to look for something like `levenshtein` `function`.But as you need sub strings and not necessarly the whole string and  also ,in order to make the work easier for the `levenshtein function` and your server, You need to use some imagination.You could for example `break` both `haystack and needle` in words and then use `levenshtein` to find most closest values to your needles.

This is one way to achieve this .Read carefully the comments to understand the idea and you will be able to implement something better.

for strings with only ASCII chars it is relatively easy to achieve it. But for other Encodings you will probably encounter many difficulties.But a simple approach to handle multibyte strings too could be something like:

```
     function to_ascii($text,$encoding="UTF-8") {
      if (is_string($text)) {
        // Includes combinations of characters that present as a single glyph
        $text = preg_replace_callback('/\X/u', __FUNCTION__, $text);
      }
      elseif (is_array($text) && count($text) == 1 && is_string($text[0])) {
        // IGNORE characters that can't be TRANSLITerated to ASCII
        $text = @iconv($encoding, "ASCII//IGNORE//TRANSLIT", $text[0]);
        // The documentation says that iconv() returns false on failure but it returns ''
        if ($text === '' || !is_string($text)) {
          $text = '?';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/\w/', $text)) {        // If the text contains any letters...
          $text = preg_replace('/\W+/', '', $text); // ...then remove all non-letters
        }
      }
      else {  // $text was not a string
        $text = '';
      }
      return $text;
    }





function find_similar($needle,$str,$keep_needle_order=false){
    if(!is_string($needle)||!is_string($str))
    {
        return false;
    }
    $valid=array();
    //get  encodings  and words from haystack and needle
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_GB.UTF8');
    $encoding_s=mb_detect_encoding($str);
    $encoding_n=mb_detect_encoding($needle);

    mb_regex_encoding ($encoding_n);
    $pneed=array_filter(mb_split('\W',$needle));

    mb_regex_encoding ($encoding_s);
    $pstr=array_filter(mb_split('\W',$str));



    foreach($pneed as $k=>$word)//loop trough needle's words
    {
        foreach($pstr as $key=>$w)
        {
            if($encoding_n!==$encoding_s)
            {//if $encodings are not the same make some transliteration
                $tmp_word=($encoding_n!=='ASCII')?to_ascii($word,$encoding_n):$word; 
                $tmp_w=($encoding_s!=='ASCII')?to_ascii($w,$encoding_s):$w;
            }else
            {
                $tmp_word=$word;
                $tmp_w=$w;
            }

            $tmp[$tmp_w]=levenshtein($tmp_w,$tmp_word);//collect levenshtein distances
            $keys[$tmp_w]=array($key,$w);

        }

        $nominees=array_flip(array_keys($tmp,min($tmp)));//get the nominees
        $tmp=10000;
        foreach($nominees as $nominee=>$idx)
        {//test sound like to get more precision
            $idx=levenshtein(metaphone($nominee),metaphone($tmp_word));
            if($idx<$tmp){
                $answer=$nominee;//get the winner

            }
            unset($nominees[$nominee]);
        }
        if(!$keep_needle_order){
            $valid[$keys[$answer][0]]=$keys[$answer][1];//get the right form of the winner
        }
        else{
            $valid[$k]=$keys[$answer][1];
        }
        $tmp=$nominees=array();//clean a little for the next iteration
    }
    if(!$keep_needle_order)
    {
        ksort($valid);
    }

    $valid=array_values($valid);//get only the values
    /*return the array of the closest value to the 
    needle according to this algorithm of course*/
    return $valid;

}


var_dump(find_similar('i knew you love me','finally  i know you loved me and all my pets'));
var_dump(find_similar('I you love','This is a demo text and I love you about this'));
var_dump(find_similar('a unik idia','I have a unique idea. Do you need?'));
var_dump(find_similar("Goebel, Weiss, Goethe, Goethe und Goetz",'Weiß, Goldmann, Göbel, Weiss, Göthe, Goethe und Götz'));
var_dump(find_similar('Ḽơᶉëᶆ ȋṕšᶙṁ ḍỡḽǭᵳ ʂǐť ӓṁệẗ, ĉṓɲṩḙċťᶒțûɾ ấɖḯƥĭṩčįɳġ ḝłįʈ',
'Ḽơᶉëᶆ ȋṕšᶙṁ ḍỡḽǭᵳ ʂǐť ӓṁệẗ, ĉṓɲṩḙċťᶒțûɾ ấɖḯƥĭṩčįɳġ ḝłįʈ, șếᶑ ᶁⱺ ẽḭŭŝḿꝋď ṫĕᶆᶈṓɍ ỉñḉīḑȋᵭṵńť ṷŧ ḹẩḇőꝛế éȶ đꝍꞎôꝛȇ ᵯáꞡᶇā ąⱡîɋṹẵ.'));
```

and the output is:

```
    array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "i"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "know"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "you"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "loved"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "me"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "I"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "love"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "you"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "unique"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "idea"
}
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Göbel"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Weiss"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Goethe"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "und"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "Götz"
}
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "Ḽơᶉëᶆ"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "ȋṕšᶙṁ"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "ḍỡḽǭᵳ"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "ʂǐť"
  [4]=>
  string(11) "ӓṁệẗ"
  [5]=>
  string(26) "ĉṓɲṩḙċťᶒțûɾ"
  [6]=>
  string(23) "ấɖḯƥĭṩčįɳġ"
  [7]=>
  string(9) "ḝłįʈ"
}
```

if you need the output as string you can use `join` on the result of the function before use it

[You can run  the working code and check the result online](https://3v4l.org/Mpbcg)

But you must keep in mind that this will not work for all kind of strings nor for all PHP versions

Comment: Your code works just fine for english sentences. However, I need a multibyte solution. I mean to support UTF. Please suggest for unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to find string within string

```
$data = "I have a unique idea. Do you need one?";
$find = "a unique idea";
$start = strpos($data, $find);
if($start){     
    $end = $start + strlen($find);
    print_r(substr($data, $start, strlen($find)));
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very easy way to do that:

```
$source = "This is a demo text and I love you about this";
$needle = "I you love";
$words = explode(" " , $source);
$needleWords = explode(" ", $needle);
$results = [];

foreach($needleWords as $key => $needleWord) {

    foreach($words as $keyWords => $word) {

        if(strcasecmp($word, $needleWord) == 0) {
            $results[$keyWords] = $needleWord;
        }
    }
}
uksort($results, function($a , $b) {
    return $a - $b;
});
echo(implode(" " , $results));
```

**Output**

```
I love you
```

Comment: Your code works just fine for english sentences. However, as I said earlier I need multibyte solution. I mean to support UTF. Please suggest for unicode.

Comment: Can you provide me failing test?

Answer (score 0):

Use this function it checks any length string

```
function sim($aa,$bb){

    $l1 = strlen($aa);
    $l2 = strlen($bb);
    if ($l1 > $l2) {
        $a = $bb;
        $b = $aa;
    }else{
        $a = $aa;
        $b = $bb;
    }

    // Format string
    $a = explode(" ", implode(" ", array_unique(explode(" ", preg_replace("~\b[a-z]{1,2}\b\s*~", "", $a)))));
    $b = explode(" ", implode(" ", array_unique(explode(" ", preg_replace("~\b[a-z]{1,2}\b\s*~", "", $b)))));
    sort($a);
    sort($b);
    $a = implode(" ",$a);
    $b = implode(" ",$b);
    $a = strtolower(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/", " ", $a));
    $b = strtolower(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/", " ", $b));

    $dc2 = count(array_diff(str_split($a,2),str_split($b,2)));
    $cA1 = count(str_split($a)); 
    $cB1 = count(str_split($b));

    $a  = explode(" ",$a);
    $b  = explode(" ",$b);
    $dc = count(array_diff($a, $b));

    $cA = count($a); 
    $cB = count($b);

    // Calculate similarity
    $p  = (((($cA + $cB) / 2) - $dc) * 100) / (($cA + $cB) / 2);
    $p2 = ((((($cA1 / 2) + ($cB1 / 2)) / 2) - $dc2) * 100) / ((($cA1 / 2) + ($cB1 / 2)) / 2);

    $percent = ($p + $p2) / 2;

    echo $percent . " %";
}
```